# How to open Android keyboard show only custom digits in Android

Tags: android, searchview, android-inputtype

I want to show digits "0123456789/" on `keyboard` if open on click of `SearchView`but I don't know how it can be done. I am able to set `InputType` to a searchview like this

```
searchView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

but not able to set custom digit to show on a `keyboard`.

from input type `InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER` numeric keyboard is opening but i also want to show "/" also with numeric digits 0123456789.
I searched a lot on SO but didn't find any solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy solution for this. You have two options depending on what you can work with and what exactly you want.

1. If it is exactly as you say in your question, that is, to **SHOW**
   just the Characters that you specify, then the way to go about doing
   that would be to create a `Custom SoftKeyboard`. This will allow you
   to take only the desired inputs and will show only those characters
   that you have specified.
2. Otherwise you can disable taking other
   characters input (that are not to be available), by working with
   `[onQueryTextChanged]`[1](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.OnQueryTextListener.html) where you manipulate to resend only the
   values that you can take in as input. Here the default
   softKeyboard is used, but the input taken in by the SearchView are
   as per specification.

Note : my knowledge is mainly based on working with `EditText` rather than `SearchView`, so not able to provide exact codes for the above

Comment: thanks creating `Custom SoftKeyboard` will work i think, will create it

Comment: Sure. Glad to help.